# Login php y variables de sesión

Tags: php, php7

Hola a todos estoy tratando de hacer que el usuario cuando inicie sesión, no pueda regresar al login ya que su sesión esta activa pero no logro hacerlo. El primer caso es que si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión no le permita pasar a la ruta admin/index.php y eso me funciona, pero cuando el usuario inicia sesión me deja regresar a la ruta ../index.php y eso no puede pasar si no hasta que cierre sesión.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] !== true || !isset($_SESSION['ruta']) || $_SESSION['ruta'] !== 'admin/index.php') {
    header("location: ../index.php");
    die;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) && $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] === true && isset($_SESSION['ruta']) && $_SESSION['ruta'] === 'admin/index.php') {
    // El usuario ha iniciado sesión y está en la ruta correcta, no se realiza ninguna redirección.
} else {
    header("location: ../index.php");
    die;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código es bastante redundante y confusa, tratemos de simplificarlo hasta obtener el resultado esperado.

---

Primero necesitas validar que si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión, le redirija a la ruta `../index.php`, bastaría con esta validación:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] !== true) {
    header("location: ../index.php");
    die;
}
```

Ahora, si el usuario no ingresa al primer `if`, es decir, si está logeado, pasamos a la siguiente validación, donde validamos que si el usuario no se encuentra en la ruta `admin/index.php`, redirigiendo a esa misma ruta, así no ingresaría nunca al login:

```
elseif ($_SESSION['ruta'] !== 'admin/index.php') {
    header("location: admin/index.php");
}
```

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] !== true) {
    header("location: ../index.php");
    die;
} elseif ($_SESSION['ruta'] !== 'admin/index.php') {
    header("location: admin/index.php");
}
?>
```